# session not expiring when browser closes

Tags: php, session, browser, global

I have a few $_SESSION variables that keep track of what page the user comes from. This way, I can make the error messages more specific and thus the web app more user friendly. When a user does not come from any page, there is supposed to be a "welcome" message at the top of the main page. However, when I close the browser and access the main page, I get the message corresponding to the page I linked from prior to closing the session. This is my function:

```
function come_from($from_page, $updates_occurred) { 
    $message = "";
    if ($updates_occurred == false) {
        $message .= "Welcome to the User List.<br/>";
        $message .= "Select the user you wish to update, or add a new user. ";
    } elseif ($from_page == "edit_user.php") {
        $message .= "The user was successfully updated";
    } else { 
        $message .= "The user was successfully added";
    }
return $message; 
}
```

At the top of the main page, I have the following code:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['updates_occurred'])) {
    $updates_occurred = $_SESSION['updates_occurred'];
} else {
    $updates_occurred = false;
}

if (isset($_SESSION['come_from'])) {
    $come_from = $_SESSION['come_from'];
} else {
    $come_from = NULL;
    echo "got here";
}


echo come_from($come_from, $updates_occurred);
```

*updates_occurred just keeps track of whether a user was successfully edited/added on the previous page.

I guess my main concern is: is there a problem with the way I am using the session variables? If my understanding is correct, session variables are supposed to expire when the browser is closed, right?

Comment: oops I feel very rude: thank you to anyone in advance!

Comment: Did you close the whole browser (every tab, every window) or just the tab? For better or worse, session cookies continue to live in most (all?) browsers while there are any tabs/windows open, you have to close everything to destroy them.

Comment: Great, that was the issue. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closing Browser tabs doesn't close the session

You should close whole browser to close the session

Comment: I think this should be a comment.

Comment: whatever comment or answer ... the matter is to be useful for him

Comment: *her ;-). But thank you, that was useful. You are right, when I closed the browser the "Welcome" message sent!